# Fullscreen HTML5 video to big?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I'm building a website with a fullscreen HTML5 video on the homepage.

my HTML:

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <div class="overlay-video"></div>
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="assets/images/background.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="assets/video/background.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="assets/video/background.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="assets/video/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

My .webm file is 4,7mb, the .OGG file is 4,4mb and the .mp4 file is 37,1mb.

My problem is that my website is still really slow. Are my video files to big? Or is there a problem with my  tag and the way I load the videos?

I can not find any solutions for this on internet so I hope someone knows a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked in different browsers

Comment: Yes, on IE11, edge and Safari it is really slow but the rest of the browsers are not really fast as well

Comment: Why aren't you using `width:100%`?

Comment: And it is also depends upon your internet speed, if your testing it in live @WilcoVanMeppelenScheppink

Comment: If my answer helped you, PLEASE set my answer as correct. Click the check next to my answer. @WilcoVanMeppelenScheppink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove below mentioned line and video then test it. If it is loading fast, then it is having issues with the size of `.mp4` video.

```
    <source src="assets/video/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Great, I think this is the problem indeed. Now it works fast in firefox etc. but edge and internet explorer don't have the video now.

Comment: Yeah because those browsers will only support `.mp4` . Try to reduce the file size and include it in the code @WilcoVanMeppelenScheppink

Comment: Check the link here [Browser_Support](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the resolution and the length of the mp4 (now 7mb) video but now chrome and firefox are using the mp4 video to... and not the ogg and web file. How is this possible?

Comment: Browser will check the best extension available and WebM and Ogg extensions are new file types related to HTML5 video @WilcoVanMeppelenScheppink